# C++ Vector element constructor not called

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, move-semantics, reference-counting

I have a class with a copy constructor and move constructor, both of which report messages to stdout until I figure this problem out. When pushing a local object onto a vector, no constructor is ever called, leading to later problems. However, when I use std::move to tell it to use the move constructor instead of the copy constructor, everything works fine. Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding how std::vector operates?

These are my object's constructors:

```
template <typename R>
inline Ref (const Ref<R> &other)
: m_ptr(other.m_ptr)
{
  LogDebugc("copy ctor ", long(other.m_ptr));
  Retain(m_ptr);
}

template <typename R>
inline Ref (Ref<R> &&other)
: m_ptr(other.m_ptr)
{
  LogDebugc("move ctor ", long(other.m_ptr));
  other.m_ptr = nullptr;
}
```

And here's where the problem occurs:

```
void SetState (State *state)
{
  // Keep a reference so we don't free the state by mistake
  Ref<State> ref (state);

  s_stateStack.clear();
  if (ref) {
    LogDebugc("pre push ", long(state));
    s_stateStack.push_back(ref);
    LogDebugc("post push ", long(state));
  }
}
```

I'm expecting to get the output...

```
[dbg] pre push 6415744
[dbg] copy ctor 6415744
[dbg] post push 6415744
```

...but instead, I'm getting...

```
[dbg] pre push 6415744
[dbg] post push 6415744
```

When I change the line where the state is pushed back, I get:

```
s_stateStack.push_back(std::move(ref));

[dbg] pre push 6415744
[dbg] move ctor 6415744
[dbg] post push 6415744
```

This is deeply confusing me.

Comment: What does retain do, that's the diff between your 2 functions

Comment: Your question talks about vectors but I don't see any.

Comment: Is it possible that push_back on a vector does member by member assignment?  As in, it calls operator=() and not copy constructors?

Comment: @BenVoigt the vector is the statestack thing, there isn't much code provided though

Comment: Without seeing how you have declared s_stateStack, my guess is that it is declared as a vector of references rather than instances.

Comment: @aaronman: `m_stateStack` sounds like a `std::stack`, but it could just as easily be a `std::list`.  Or a `std::deque`.  I want to see the declaration (including any non-default allocator policy).

Comment: s_stateStack is a std::vector<Ref<State>>. I've overloaded operator= as well, so it should show debug messages for those too.

Comment: @Daggerbot: Put the declaration in the question, in a code region, where `*` and `&` don't get eaten by grues.

Comment: [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=07c48af7173b780130b3a25befafb21d-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
template <typename R>
inline Ref (const Ref<R> &other)
: m_ptr(other.m_ptr)
{
  LogDebugc("copy ctor ", long(other.m_ptr));
  Retain(m_ptr);
}
```

That is not a copy constructor.  As such, it's not being called.

> § 12.8 A **non-template** constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments

The compiler is using the implicitly generated copy constructor rather than the *conversion* constructor that you wrote.

Comment: Just realized that as well.  But let's find one of the dozen existing questions, shall we?

Comment: This did in fact turn out to be the problem. Fixed! :D